# vba check if cell is empty before writing to it and cycle through list of names in turn

Tags: vba, excel

This is my code I have 2 problems.

1. The code all works fine but it needs to check if the cell that it is about to write to in "Allocation" holds the value "X1" or "X" if it does then it needs to go to the next person in the list, the peoples names are held in column A. **I have solved this bit myself so it is just the last question I need help with now**
2. Each time the loop starts the program needs to check who the last person to be allocated was and start the next allocation from the next persons name in the list of names. If it would help I could post the whole workbook so you can see what it is all doing but you would have to tell me how to do it as I can't seem to find a way of attaching a file. Thank you for looking and any help that may be offered

   ```
   Public Sub copyothers()
   Dim listofcells As Range
   Dim currentname As String
   Dim foundrow As Integer
   Dim foundcolumn As Integer
   Dim counter As Integer
   Dim i As Integer
   Dim personcount() As Variant


   Sheets("Availability").Activate

   personcount = Sheets("Availability").Range("B3:AR3").Value 'check the 
   number of people required in each column and record it for later

   For i = 2 To 44
        Sheets("Availability").Activate
        Sheets("Availability").Range("a2").Select

        counter = personcount(1, i - 1) - 1 'take the first number reduce 
        it by 1 and move one column right right each time program loops
        If Not Sheets("Availability").Cells(2, i) = "" Then
        Sheets("Availability").Range(Cells(2, i), Cells(2, 
        i).End(xlDown)).Select
        Else
        GoTo skip:  'If the column has no data then skip to next column
         End If
        Set listofcells = Selection

        Sheets("allocation").Activate
        Range("a2").Select


        For Each singlecell In listofcells
       If counter > 0 Then
           If singlecell = "Available" Then
           foundcolumn = singlecell.Column 'record the column number where 
           "Available" was found
           currentname = Sheets("Availability").Range("A" & singlecell.Row) 
           'record the name of the person in the row where "Available" was 
            found
           Set foundName = 
   Sheets("Allocation").Range("A:A").Find(What:=currentname, 
    LookIn:=xlValues) 'find the persons name in "Allocation" sheet
           foundrow = foundName.Row
               If Sheets("allocation").Cells(foundrow, foundcolumn) = "" 
       Then
               Sheets("allocation").Cells(foundrow, foundcolumn) = "X" 
        'place X in the same cell as it appeared in "Availability" sheet
               counter = counter - 1
               End If
           End If
       End If

       Next singlecell

         skip:
         Next i

      End Sub
   ```

Image form Availability Sheet
[image: availability]

Image form Allocation Sheet
[image: Allocation]

Comment: It will help if you could add a screen shot of your `Availability x1` sheet and the `Aollocation` sheet to then see how it is processing the data.

Comment: I have added a sample view of the 2 worksheets this is operating on. there is another worksheet in the same work and a lot more programming going on but if you need more info I would be happy to supply it